# Using message queue in front of Redis, or between Redis -> database?

Tags: java, mongodb, redis

I have a simple use case:

- Newsfeeds aggregated based on posts that are linked to geopoints
- Users can comment on feed posts
- Users can like feed posts and comments

The question I'm dealing with is whether I should (in case of high load):

> Rest endpoint -> Redis -> Message queue -> Database

Or:

> Rest endpoint -> Message queue -> Redis -> Database

The plan is to work primarily with Redis as write-behind cache.
This way I have all 'hot' feed items and social info in Redis, and can retrieve older data from the database in case the user requests it.

I don't have a lot of experience with high load applications like this, and not too sure about where the bottleneck would most probably lie.
My guess would be that option 1 is the safest, although I'm not certain.
What is your advice?

Comment: if you are going for high speed transaction i would do redis > message queue > database. Think like this, changes in redis will go fast since they are in memory, so the value can change a lot very fast and give quick feedback to clients. Then at certain intervals you can flush the cache to the database and dump a large amount of records to the queue, that the database can read off and store. If you have a crash, you will loose what you had in the cache, but hopefully the latest dump is beeing read off the queue and you might only loose say 30 mins of the latest changes

Comment: the bottleneck without a doubt is writes to the database.

Comment: @Toerktumlare I could fix this by implementing acknowledgements and only return positive http status code when at least the message is successfully placed on the queue. Dead letter queues could then still handle failed posts. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: But if i was to like a comment during heavy load and then reload the page i would get a non updated state, meaning that you need to try to keep the state in the client matching the “soon to be” state in the backend. Id go with the high speed in memory handled state which was the the way we did it when i used to work in the betting buisness

Comment: Did you check the Redis module Write-Behind solution? See https://github.com/RedisGears/rgsync

Comment: @GuyKorland It's interesting, but I'm not too sure I trust it. System failure will cause some posts to be lost, which imo is not acceptable for a social network. If a user visited some place and loses a local post that is irrecoverable, then you're losing users. I think I should be able to write something custom in Java to at least get some acknowledgement that a post is written to a queue to decrease the risk of losing messages.

Comment: I just checked high availability Redis, but this is currently too expensive for my wallet, unfortunately.

Comment: You should check Redis Enterprise Cloud it even has a free tier